# Fitting in buckets with multiple `OR` rules

Tags: algorithm

I have a block trying to solve an algorithmic problem:

Given these rules:
**50** items could go into either bucket **A** or **C**
**100** items could go into either bucket **A** or **B**
**50** items could go into either bucket **B** or **D**

I want to know: Am I allowed to put X more items in bucket Y?

For example, with these populated items:
**B** already contains *90*
**C** already contains *30*
**D** already contains *40*

*D* was filled with 40, leaving room of 10 in the 3rd rule.
*B* was filled with 90 - using 10 of 3rd rule and 80 out of the 2nd rule.
*C* was filled with 30.
We are left with a space of 20 for A/C in 1st rule + 20 for A/B in the 2nd rule.

The algorithm should return:

- `true` for 40 in A
- `false` for 50 in A
- `false` for 20 in D

Now this is more about "am I allowed" rather than "do I have space", as the rules are defined as constraints.

This is a very simplified version of the actual problem, but solving this will solve the bigger picture :-)

At first this may look like the KnapSack problem, but it is not, as we do not need find the best or max to fit in the buckets. We only need to find whether we can actually fit.

Also - quantities are not necessarily whole numbers,

Comment: I don't get your constraints. When you say "50 elements can go in A or C" and "100 elements can go in A or B" what dies that mean for "A"? And what is the difference between " is there space" and "am I allowed to"?

Comment: This means that there's no strict constraints like "A has a capacity of 150", so it's not a "capacity" issue. It's more about rules and constraints. So A could have 150 - if C and B are empty. But if I filled C with 40 items, then A could have only 110. But it's even more complex, as there could be other similar rules involving C, so we do not know from where to subtract quantities to get a straight answer.

Comment: Let's assume all buckets are empty. Following rule 2, "100 in A" should return true, right? But if B already contains 90 elements, "100 in A" should return false (because rule 2 can't be applied anymore)? That doesn't make much sense ...

Comment: But if that's the case, it's more or less a knapsack problem, because  you will have to try different permutations of fillings, whether they can be satisfied or not

Comment: @derpirscher I agree that it does not make much sense, but it may provide the fullest solution we want for a customer. I also agree that it resembles the KnapSack problem, but it's not quite. And it's always much more complex when it's not whole numbers, historically it's not yet fully solved. Now maybe someone will have an idea that will work, so I put it here :-)

Comment: After reading this question several times, I can't piece together why those should be the expected outputs on those inputs, or what the question is precisely asking. Please edit in an explanation of why that's the expected output, and further clarification of the constraints. The usual meaning of `50 items could go into either bucket A or C` is probably `at most one of (A, C) contains 50 items`, which seems to be different from what you want.

Comment: @kcsquared edited to make it clearer